# VideoCapturer.startCamera(width, height, fps) crops the Camera with different width,height android

Tags: android, webrtc, android-camera, video-capture, video-tracking

I want to open my camera and capture video for video call in an Android application.
First i create a videoCapturer with this

```
private fun createCameraCapturer(): VideoCapturer? {
        val enumerator: CameraEnumerator = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Camera2Enumerator(context)
        } else {
            Camera1Enumerator(false)
        }

        // Try to find front facing camera
        enumerator.deviceNames.forEach {
            if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(it)) {
                videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(it, null)
                if (videoCapturer != null) return videoCapturer
            }
        }


        // Front facing camera not found, try something else
        enumerator.deviceNames.forEach {
            if (!enumerator.isFrontFacing(it)) {
                videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(it, null)
                if (videoCapturer != null) return videoCapturer
            }
        }

        return null
    }
```

After i get a non-null videoCapturer i start the cameraCapture with given width,height and fps.

```
videoCapturer?.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, context, videoSource?.capturerObserver)
videoCapturer?.startCapture(width, height, fps)
```

The possible combinations of width and height are the following

```
0 -> VideoHeader(fps: 5, height: 128, width: 96
1 -> VideoHeader(fps: 5, height: 320, width: 240
2 -> VideoHeader(fps: 10, height: 480, width: 360
3 -> VideoHeader(fps: 10, height: 640, width: 480
4 -> VideoHeader(fps: 15, height: 960, width: 720
```

I notice that there is a crop in the video that i get in the UI view according to the VideoHeader. For example if i have the case: 0  then the participant is cropped in the right top side of his face. Like there is a zoom or something.
Is there any way that i could solve this issue?

Comment: are you using SurfaceView to render the stream?

Comment: No...i am using <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer /> which extends the SurfaceView

"""public class SurfaceViewRenderer extends SurfaceView implements Callback, VideoSink, RendererEvents"""

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code on SurfaceViewRenderer instance:

```
surfaceviewrenderer.setScaleType(Scaletofit)
```

This would not give zoom effect on stream and not cropped the stream.
You can play around `setScaleType` as per your need

Comment: Did you try above solution?

Comment: Thats what i am doing but nothing changes

Comment: Try other scale type surfaceviewrenderer.setScalingType(ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT)

Comment: is this happening for local stream only?